# Can't schedule post for another time

Tags: publish, post-status

Very odd thing happening - suddenly, I can't click on the "Edit" link under the Publish options. That is, I can hit "Publish" but if I want to change the publishing date/time or visibility or status, I can't click "Edit" under any of those. Or when I click it, nothing happens.

Help?